# Different color schemes on vim

Tags: vim, fortran

In my lab, I can either work directly on my work station or on some server that is made available to us. On both my accounts, I have the same `.bashrc` and `.vimrc` files. Now looking at the picture below, you can see that there is some minor difference about the two color schemes my vim is showing for my sample Fortran code:

1. The `CALL` statement
2. The `PROCEDURE` statement
3. The red bar on the right that shows the 81st column of my code.

Here is my `.vimrc` file:

```
syntax enable                                                                    

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.f90 set filetype=fortran                                 

set smartindent                                                                  
set tabstop=4                                                                    
set shiftwidth=4                                                                 
set ruler               "Show line number at bottom right corner"                
set smartcase           "CaseSensitive search only if contains uppercase letters"
set so=999              "Have cursors always at center of the screen"            
nnoremap <C-L> :nohlsearch<CR><C-L>                                              

hi link fortranTab NONE                                                          

if exists('+colorcolumn')                                                        
    set colorcolumn=81                                                           
else                                                                             
    au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)              
endif
```

[image: Comparing my two color schemes]

On my workstation, Vim and the Vim syntax file are versions 7.3 and 0.93 respectively, while on my server 7.2 and 0.88.

Any idea why this happens and how I fix it?

Comment: Do those systems have the same Vim version? Check with `:version`. Also, compare the versions of the used syntax script (`:edit $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/fortran.vim`).

Comment: @IngoKarkat On my workstation, Vim and the Vim syntax file are versions 7.3 and 0.93 respectively, while on my server 7.2 and 0.88.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Updating vim is trivial with `sudo apt-get` but how do i update my syntax file?

Comment: The syntax file is part of the Vim runtime; it ships with Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On my workstation, Vim and the Vim syntax file are versions 7.3 and 0.93 respectively, while on my server 7.2 and 0.88.

That explains it. The `'colorcolumn`' was introduced in Vim 7.3. Your `~/.vimrc` has a fallback using `matchadd()` for older versions, but that one only highlights actual occurrences that exceed the width, not a continuous line.

The different Vim versions ship with different syntax scripts, in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/fortran.vim`. Updating Vim will automatically get you a corresponding newer version of the syntax script, as it's part of the runtime.

For custom syntax scripts (that you've downloaded somewhere, e.g. from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/)), or to get the latest and greatest of the Fortran syntax (my Vim version 7.4.716 has version 0.95 from 2015 Jan. 15), you'd have to download a new one and place it into `~/.vim/syntax/`, where it would override the runtime one. (But then you have to maintain that copy yourself in case of Vim updates.)

Comment: Thanks for that, it just fixed it.

Comment: Question: how do I find out where the variable `$VIMRUNTIME` points to?

Comment: @solalito: Inside Vim, just `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`